# wampserver is not sending Emails local?

Tags: php, email

i am trying to make my wamp server supportable for sending emails offline without using any hosting website.
i just try to do couple of ways to implement it but can't.
after long research i find a way but as per follow instruction but still it cannot work.

simply i just download send-mail.zip
and extract on to a folder in F:\wamp\sendmail\

**sendmail.ini**
what i configure in it

- smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
- smtp_port=465
- smtp_ssl=ssl
- default_domain=localhost
- error_logfile=error.log
- debug_logfile=debug.log
- auth_username=*****@gmail.com
- auth_password=********

**after enabling POP/IMAP from gmail account**

**php.ini** what i configure in it

- ;SMTP =
- ;smtp_port = 25
- ;sendmail_from = snavjot969@yahoo.com
- sendmail_path ="F:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
- ;mail.force_extra_parameters =

**and the php code that i used to send email on localhost:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$to = "ns949405@gmail.com,snavjot969@yahoo.com";
$header = "from: $name<$email>";
$message = "Name:$name \n\n
            email:$email \n\n
            subject:$subject \n\n\
            message:$comment";
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$header))
{
    echo "email sent";

}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
}
```

when i press submit button it show **error**. 
any help is appreciated.
thank-you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at PHPMailer - you can use this instead of the built in mail() function. Within PHPMailer you can specify the SMTP host name, username and password.

Comment: thank-you sir but i already try it same problem occur